# Issue while converting column value to row value in pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like

```
County  section
 A       S1,S2
 C       ALL
 B       S1
```

**Expected Output**

```
County    section
A          S1
A          S2
C          S1
C          S2
B          S2
```

My code

```
df =df.assign(sections=df.sections.replace({'ALL':df.loc[df.sections.str.split(',').str.len().idxmax(),'sections']}).str.split(',')).explode('sections')
```

But the above code only works when we have comma separated multiple sections (S1,S2,S3) . But doesn't work when we have section value without comma separated as shown below. How can make the code to work for both scenarios together

```
County  Section
A       ALL
B       S1
C       ALL
D       ALL
```

**Expected Output**

```
  County  Section
    A       S1
    B       S1
    C       S1
    D       S1
```

Code should work in both scenarios

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. Please see this post on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the very least, we need you to fully specify the logic you're looking to implement and why the code you've provided doesn't satisfy it.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, Please have a look now . I made it more clear now

Comment: Why are there two **Expected Output** and they are different?

Comment: @QuangHoang, The outputs are not different . In case1, we have values multiple values which are separated by commas. But in Case 2 we have only one value instead multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us change the `replace` part

```
s=df[df.section.ne('ALL')]
toreplace=s.loc[s.section.str.split(',').str.len().idxmax(),'section']
df.assign(section=df.section.replace({'ALL':toreplace}).str.split(',')).explode('section')
  County section
0      A      S1
1      B      S1
2      C      S1
3      D      S1
```

Comment: I tried this case1,Its replacing ALL with  S1,S2 but not creating new rows for S1 and S2 .

Comment: `df =df.assign(sections=df.sections.replace({'ALL':toreplace}).str.split(',')).explode('sections') ` made this change

Comment: This seems to work only if some county contains all the sections. Will likely fail if county `A` has sections `S1,S2` and county `B` has section `S3,S4`.

Answer (score 0):

A little late for the party:

```
all_sec = df.section.eq('ALL')
non_sec_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'section']

df1 = (df.drop('section', axis=1)
         .join(df.loc[~all_sec, 'section'].str.get_dummies(','))
         .fillna(1)
         .melt(non_sec_cols, var_name='section')
         .query('value==1')
         .drop('value', axis=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
  County section
0      A      S1
1      C      S1
2      B      S1
3      A      S2
4      C      S2
```